# How do I find the area bounded by these two curves?

Tags: integration

Find the area bounded by the curves $y_1=x^2$ and $y_2=1+2x-x^2$.

I need to know how to slove this kind of question step by step.

> $y_1=y_2$ gives $x=a=\frac{1-\sqrt3}2$ and $x=b=\frac{1+\sqrt3}2$.

([original screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUBf4.png))

i doubted with how a and b gives.please explain.

Comment: What's your background? What have you tried?

Comment: Try to make a figure of the area, that should clear some bits up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the other answers simply assume that the calculation of the integral is trivial. However If you do not have a black belt in pre-algebra, the steps can be somewhat demanding. 
Like the previous answers showed we have

$$
   \int_{x_0}^{x_1} (-x^2+2x+1)-(x^2)\,\mathrm{d}t
   = \left[ - \frac 23 x^3 + x^2 + x \right]_{x_0}^{x_1} \tag{1}
$$
Where $x_0$ and $x_1$ are exactly the same as you calculated, eg $x_0 = (1-\sqrt{3})/2$ and $x_1 = (1+\sqrt{3})/2$. Note that $x_0$ and $x_1$ satisfies
$$
-x^2 + 2x + 1 = x^2 \quad \Rightarrow \ -2x^2 + 2x + 1 = 0 \tag{2} 
$$ 
which can be written as
$$
  x^2 = \frac{1}{2} + x \tag{3}
$$
Returning to the integrand $(1)$ can be rewritten as
$$
\begin{align*}
        -\frac{2}{3}x^3 + x^2 + x 
    & =  \frac{1}{3}x(\color{red}{-2x^2+2x+1})+\frac{1}{3}(\color{blue}{x^2}+2x) \\
    & =  \frac{1}{3}x\cdot \color{red}{0} + \frac{1}{3}\left(\color{blue}{\frac{1}{2}   +x}+2x\right) \\ 
    & = \frac{1}{6} + x
\end{align*}
$$
Where we used $(2)$ and $(3)$. Plugging everything back into $(1)$ we now have
$$
   \int_{x_0}^{x_1} (-x^2+2x+1)-(x^2)\,\mathrm{d}t
   = \left[ \frac{1}{6} + x_1 \right] - \left[\frac{1}{6} + x_0\right]
   = x_1 - x_0
$$
The value of $x_1-x_0$ can easily be evaluated from the closed expressions earlier.

Comment: could i know how x^2=1/2+x gives x0=(1−3√)/2 and x1=(1+3√)/2?

Comment: Use the quadratic formula like normal $ax^2 +bx + c = 0 \ \Rightarrow \ x = \frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$.

Answer (score 3):

You found the limits (the points of intersection of both curves.)

$$\begin{align} \text{Area} & =\int_{\frac{1-\sqrt 3}2}^{\frac{1+\sqrt 3}2} (\text{upper curve} - \text{lower curve})\,dx\\ 
&= \int_{\frac{1-\sqrt 3}2}^{\frac{1+\sqrt 3}2} \Big((1+2x-x^2)- (x^2)\Big)\,dx
\end{align}$$

Comment: @200_success  i made a mistake. i looked at joetaxpayers graph; it is plain there. now we know that it is symmetric, we can argue better. the difference is a quadratic expression. and quad expressions are symmetric about $-b/(2a).$

Answer (score 2):

A hint for you - the graphs look like this -

[image]

Comment: gotta love desmos!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: area enclosed = difference in areas between limits you have found from the intersection